# Pardot Marketing Fields access in Salesforce

Tags: pardot

I would like to get Pardot Marketing activity fields objects to create Trigger in SalesForce. However, I don't see that any Pardot Marketing Activity Field. Any body has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately Pardot Marketing activity is not currently a custom object, but a visualforce page, so there are no fields to access.